# how can i read value from register using C++

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

I am writhing code with C++ for a calculator  ,but it display\read results with assembly,I want to store the  value in any register for example( Al )to variable  int in C++... I searched for away but  I always find it with C language  ...

Comment: Do you mean like in the `register` keyword?

Comment: I think he means assembly registers such as `eax`, `ebx`, ... ?!

Comment: @SJuan76 `register` has nothing to do with registers. Most compilers even ignore it after parsing.

Comment: @rightfold I [disagree](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Reg-Vars.html).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I suggest you read that. That’s not the same kind of `register` that OP is talking about. It’s a language extension which happens to use that keyword.

Comment: @rightfold Fair enough. I did read it, but took the usage of the keyword liberally.  However, I still disagree that "`register` has nothing to to do with registers". It is still a *hint* that a variable should be kept live in a register, and in GCC at `-O0` a `register` variable is [allowed to be kept in a register](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2010-05/msg00116.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to read value in `al` into an `int`:

GCC:

```
unsigned char out;
asm volatile("movb %%al, %[Var]" : [Var] "=r" (out));
```

Or

```
unsigned char out;
asm volatile("movb %%al, %0" : "=r" (out));
```

For MSVC:

```
unsigned char c;
__asm movb c, al
```

There's no official C++ way, it stems it from C.

**EDIT**

You might also want:

```
register unsigned char out asm("%al");
```

But that's GCC.

Comment: Since we're dealing with x86 assembly, I think it would be best to avoid a variable named [`out`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_222.html).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The compiler should be smart enough to handle this

Comment: @user9000 I never suggested that it couldn't. I'm only saying that, when glancing through inline assembly, seeing the word `out` is unnecessarily confusing / requires a second glance. Especially when you look at assembly a lot, and get used to an `out` catching your eye.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart ah, I didn't know you were pointing out at the MSVC code, thanks for that

Answer (score 3):

It is compiler dependent. For Intel with GCC:

```
//Read value from register
int x;

asm ("mov %0, AI;"
     :"=r"(x)
    );
```

Reference [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html)

Comment: this is my code int c;
    __asm
    {
       mov ah, 00h 
     int 16h  //store it in regester al 
  asm ("mov %0, al;":"=r"(x));
 
 }

Comment: @Sarah, you can edit your question with this? it's difficult to understand what you're doing. I take it you're working with MS compiler?

Comment: @Sarah Again it is compiler dependent. If you are using MSVC, this is a different story. Google will help

Answer (score 3):

You mean like:

```
int read_register_eax()
{
    int ret;
    asm { mov [ret],eax }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: thnnx alot for your help