# In Windows 64bits, how to "put" a register value from an .asm file, in a C++ variable?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64

My goal is to put a value from a register from the asm code/file in a variable in my c++ code. My issue is that i could do this just fine with inline assembly in 32 bits but, is it even possible with a asm file, as if i understand correctly there is no way to use inline asm with for a 64bits programs.
I understand that the asm file has not idea what MyVal is, but how could i "link" those 2?

```
This is my c++ file:
#include <iostream>
extern "C" int myAsm();
int myVal = 0;

int main()
{
    myAsm();
    std::cout << "MyVal is: " << myVal << std::endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}


This is my .asm file:

.code
myAsm proc
    mov myVal, eax
    ret
myAsm endp
end
```

EDIT: screenshot of the errors after implementing suggestions:

[image: Build Errors]

Comment: > there is no way to use inline asm with for a 64bits programs_ You can use inline assembly on most (if not all) architectures.

Comment: Use something like `EXTERN myVal: SDWORD`. And yeah, make sure you link the objects together.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895038/how-can-i-read-value-from-register-using-c

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from simply passing address of variable to the function?

Comment: Not sure about visual studio, but in NASM you would write `.extern myVal` to tell the assembler that `myVal` is something defined in a different file

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot the asm code should be called by another process as i'm doing mid function hooking, which should call the asm code that will be inside a __declspec(naked) function which itself will be in a codecave...But i also just realized that __declspec(naked) might not be possible for 64 bits. @ Jester it doesn't work. @ Maciej Polański : thank you but this is a question for x86. @ user253751 the .extern syntax triggers a syntax error

Comment: @EncoderX Just tested it. Jester and user253751 solutions (obviously) work. If you have any more detail you need to share, edit the question. As you worded your comment, this seems an XY-problem.

Comment: @Margaret Bloom Thank you for testing it, i just edited my post with a screenshot of the errors.

Comment: But have you at least tried to convert the suggestions above [to MASM syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/extern-masm?view=msvc-170)?

Comment: @Margaret Bloom You were right i didn't try hard enough, and did not read enough, tbh i was a bit frustrated. It now works, thank you so much.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer. This lets the system know that the question has been answered so that other users with the same question can find the solution.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot while it's not really the fault of the x64 architecture itself, it is also the case that MSVC rejects inline assembly when compiling for x64 (and not when compiling for 32-bit x86), so OP really can't use inline assembly here

Comment: ... unless they want to switch compilers, like to `clang-cl` which is pretty close to MSVC compatible, but it's inline asm support doesn't suck so actually does work on all architectures.

Answer (score 2):

This is the full solution thanks to people who commented. (I can not accept my own answer right away because of the 2 days delay.)
How to recreate in Visual Studio 2022 Community:

- New project => C++ Console App
- Right Click on Project name => Buid Depedencies => Build
  Customisation => tick the box called: masm(.targets, .props) =>
  click OK.
- Right Click on Project name =>    Add => new item => C++ file => but
  set the extension of the file to .asm instead    of .cpp
- Set project to Release and 64 bits.
- Set the files as shown below
- Press Ctrl + F5 to start without debugging. (i didn't change    any
  other build options other than the default ones with a c++    console
  app project).

C++ file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C" int myAsm();
extern "C" long myVal = 0;


int main()
{
    myAsm();
    std::cout << "MyVal is: " << myVal << std::endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

asm file:

```
EXTERN myVal: dword

.code
myAsm proc
    mov eax, 1234
    mov myVal, eax
    ret
myAsm endp
end
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: can you add the compilation commands if someone wants to replicate?

Comment: @Seki i didn't build using the command line but used the Ctrl+F5 in Visual Studio, and used the default build settings from a c++ console app project. I just edited the  post with a detailed walkthrough and a screenshot of the whole screen. However does that answer your question or do you want me to add more info? Are you talking about specific options in the Configuration Properties of the project that you want me to output here?

Comment: if the .asm file is assembled and linked automatically with the rest of the sources, it's fine. I did not play with Visual Studio for a looong time :)